# Ethernet port on thinkpad doesn't connect but the one on the ultrabase (dock) does

Tags: networking, xubuntu, xfce, thinkpad, ethernet

I just recently bought a used Thinkpad X200s and installed Xubuntu 13.04 on it. I am have issues getting the ethernet port on the laptop to connect. I also have a Ultrabase dock for the laptop. While docked, the ethernet port on the Ultrabase connects perfectly. Whether the laptop is docked or not the its own ethernet port won't connect. However, the ethernet port on the laptop does light up when a cable is plugged into it when it isn't docked. It doesn't light up at all when it's docked.

My current theory is that because I installed Xubuntu with the laptop docked and the ethernet plugged into the dock this caused port on the laptop to not be setup. From looking at my network settings in xfce it seems that only eth0 is setup and that is the port on the base. Whether the device is docked or not that is the only interface that shows up and when using the dock's port it is connected. Does this mean that the port on the laptop is completely broken or is it a software problem?

Comment: is your network VLANed? I'm experiencing something similar.

Comment: Nope it's a real network.

Comment: It looks like this is a bug. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1169244 and register yourself as one affected by the bug. [Otherwise file your own bug report.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) Bugs are off topic. See [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a bug report about this on launchpad.  You can find it at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1169244.

Comment: Good find!  It's very likely this is related to your issue, @jophde!

You may want to consider trying some of those kernels and posting your findings in there, as it appears to still be open/confirmed. Don't forget to mention your model laptop/dock.

Comment: Thanks, I will go ahead and mark this as closed since it likely fixes my issue.  I am excited to contribute.  I'll report back here too.

Answer (score 0):

Just by what you've provided, it does sound like the physical port on the side of the laptop may be having issues... is it possible for you to verify that it works in another OS, or in another state?  i.e.:  Are you dual booting?

If you see similar behavior in another OS, that's likely your port...

Also, a lot of Ethernet ports these days (but not all) have 'link lights' on the side.  Do you have any such lights on the physical jack (your dock, most likely, will have these for sure).

Comment: Yea the lights come on, one green and one yellow on either side, whenever I plug a cable into the laptop port when it is undocked. When it is docked the lights don't come on.  I can use the port on the dock though and its lights come on.

Comment: I am not dual booting it's pure Xubuntu.  Would setting up a VM be a good test?

Comment: After going through your original question and follow-ups here... it sounds like your port *should* be working, especially when undocked (as your link lights are indicating data - I assume you get 'flashing' yellow lights).  I'm leaning towards possible software issues now.